# How to Replace text ONCE one a specific line in text file?

Tags: batch-file, replace

I download these accounting reports every day and format them into something Quickbooks can import.

Quickbooks uses a 3-lined header and the first line of data is unique in that it begins with the string "TRNS" and all the following data lines begin with "SPL".

I am awfully close to automating this but I am having difficulty in writing a batch file that would rename "SPL" **on line 4** to "TRNS", without it replacing all instances of "SPL" to "TRNS".

Here is what I have based on some other postings on this site. Is there a way to make it start at line 4 and run only once?

```
set "search=SPL"
set "replace=TRNS"
set "textfile=Input.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
```

And here is a image of what the file currently looks like.

[The circled text is what needs to be replaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vSta.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please copy the *text* of the text file into your question rather than an image, because then others can copy it and test their approaches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple line counter should help:

```
set "search=SPL"
set "replace=TRNS"
set "textfile=Input.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"
set lineNr=0
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set /a lineNr+=1
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if !lineNr!==4 set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
```

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `goto` loop and [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Do all operations in a sub-routine, redirect files once only here:
< "Input.txt" > "Output.txt" call :SUB
exit /B

:SUB
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* The following `goto` loop is executed only until the matching line is found;
rem    everything beyond is handled by a single `findstr` command later: */
:LOOP
rem // Read a single line from the input data:
set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
rem /* Terminate sub-routine if an empty line is encountered;
rem    this is needed to not have an infinite loop in case no line matches;
rem    data past that point are lost: */
if not defined LINE goto :EOF
rem /* The following condition is fulfilled if the line begins with `SPL`;
rem    replace `if` by `if /I` to search case-insensitively: */
if "!LINE!"=="SPL!LINE:*SPL=!" (
    rem // Return the modified line, then continue below, leaving the loop:
    echo(TRNS!LINE:*SPL=!
) else (
    rem // Return the original line:
    echo(!LINE!
    rem // Jump to the beginning of the loop:
    goto :LOOP
)
rem /* Return the remaining data; the very last line must be terminated by a
rem    line-break, otherwise `findstr` might hang indefinitely: */
findstr "^"
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

A `goto` loop is slow, but since it is only executed until the matching line is encountered, which is the fourth one, according to your description, the overall approach is faster than using a `for /F` loop, particularly in case there are a lot of lines following, because all of them are returned by `findstr` without any parsing. However, the very last line must be terminated by a line-break; otherwise, `findstr` may hang (depending on the Windows version).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure batch solution that works as long as the first 4 lines are <= 1021 characters long, and end with \r\n (carriage return / linefeed ). I believe this is about the fastest pure batch solution possible.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
<input.txt >output.txt (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 3) do (
    set "ln="
    set /p "ln="
    echo(!ln!
  )
  set "ln="
  set /p "ln="
  echo TRNS!ln:~3!
  findstr "^"
)
```

If you have [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), then you can use:

```
jrepl "^SPL" "TRNS" /inc 4 /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

If you want to over-write the original file, then

```
jrepl "^SPL" "TRNS" /inc 4 /f input.txt /o -
```

If the number of header lines could vary, and you want to change only the first encountered line that begins with SPL, then

```
jrepl "^SPL" "skip=true;$txt=TRNS" /jq /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

or

```
jrepl "^SPL" "TRNS" /exc "/^SPL/+1:-1" /f input.txt /o output.txt
```